# Android Proguard issues

Tags: android, proguard

Using proguard seems to be quite confusing.  I am interested in simply obfuscating a few packages within my app.   I have eclipse set up in windows with the latest Android API's.  I have added the default proguard.cfg which builds my app with no problem, but when I run the app, certain functionality of the app does not work anymore.  It just does weird stuff.

Also, whenever I create a new project, it never automatically creates the proguard.cfg, I have no idea why.  But I can find it in

```
android-sdk-windows\tools\lib
```

All I am really interested in doing is obfuscating certain packages or even a couple classes in my code.  If I could do that I'd be pretty content.  Is there any simple way to just say "obfuscate THIS".  Any basic configs you guys could share?

Comment: I added a toast msg in a method where I thought it was having an issue and the exception is:  NoSuchMethodException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally added -dontshrink and -dontoptimize to the proguard.cfg because proguard was stipping out code even when I would specific -keep class xxxxx.  So now my code is obfuscated, but not optimized and shrunk, which is all I really wanted in the first place.